# Optimal parameters of video transcoding for mobile. Please advise

Tags: android, video, mobile, video-streaming, video-processing

We are building a mobile application that tries to mimic TikTok experience:

- Vertical feed of videos
- Video should start with no delay and high quality on every swipe.

Video files,transcoding & delivery we are using:

- Videos files are following the TikTok Video Length & Video Formatting Guide
- VOD HLS streaming
- Transcoding (codec h.264) via encoding.com with the configuration attached to this email
- Video files are distributed via CDN

Please advise what is the transcoding optimal configuration for targeting mobile devices and get the same experience as TikTok?

Tnascoding parameters are listed below.

```js
{
  "query": {
    "format": {
      "output": "advanced_hls",
      "stream": [
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "baseline",
          "size": "234x416",
          "framerate": "12",
          "keyframe": "36",
          "bitrate": "200k",
          "maxrate": "200k",
          "bufsize": "600",
          "audio_bitrate": "64k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "baseline",
          "size": "270x480",
          "framerate": "15",
          "keyframe": "45",
          "bitrate": "400k",
          "maxrate": "400k",
          "bufsize": "1200",
          "audio_bitrate": "64k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "baseline",
          "size": "360x640",
          "framerate": "29.97",
          "keyframe": "90",
          "bitrate": "600k",
          "maxrate": "600k",
          "bufsize": "1800",
          "audio_bitrate": "64k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "baseline",
          "size": "360x640",
          "framerate": "29.97",
          "keyframe": "90",
          "bitrate": "1200k",
          "maxrate": "1200k",
          "bufsize": "3600",
          "audio_bitrate": "96k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "main",
          "size": "540x960",
          "framerate": "29.97",
          "keyframe": "90",
          "bitrate": "1500k",
          "maxrate": "1500k",
          "bufsize": "3000",
          "audio_bitrate": "96k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "main",
          "size": "720x1280",
          "framerate": "29.97",
          "keyframe": "90",
          "bitrate": "2500k",
          "maxrate": "2500k",
          "bufsize": "4000",
          "audio_bitrate": "128k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_codec": "dolby_heaac",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "high",
          "size": "1080x1920",
          "framerate": "29.97",
          "keyframe": "90",
          "bitrate": "4000k",
          "maxrate": "4000k",
          "bufsize": "6000",
          "audio_bitrate": "128k",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "audio_only": "yes",
          "video_codec": "libx264",
          "profile": "baseline",
          "two_pass": "yes",
          "duration_precision": "4",
          "encoder": "v3",
          "audio_bitrate": "64k",
          "still_image": "first_segment",
          "video_codec_parameters": {
            "sc_threshold": "0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "pack_files": "no",
      "segmenter": "v3",
      "segment_duration": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as “optimal” every setting has a trade off. In fact HLS may be a bad choice for videos this short.

Comment: @szatmary what would be better option? why?

Comment: HLS is better for longer content, It takes a few seconds for the quality to "ramp up". With a short video, the video will be over before it reaches a good quality. Just use a normal MP4 at a sane bitrate, and try to pre cache it.